# How to create a table with math symbols in R Markdown (pdf_document)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am working on a paper in R Markdown, creating a pdf file. I'd like to create a table which contain math symbols. Below, it my simple code with a table:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r  echo=FALSE}
library(knitr); library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(A=c("Hello!", 100, "$x^2+100$"), L=c(10, "World!", "100+250*1"))
knitr::kable(df, escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE,
      caption = "An example[note]", 
      col.names = c("Left", "Right")) %>%
add_indent(c(2, 3), level_of_indent = 1.5, all_cols = TRUE) %>%
add_footnote(c("Source: Book."), notation = "symbol")

```
````

As a result, every time I knit the file the same error appears:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

I will appreciate if very much if you help me to fix this error.

Comment: I can knit your example without error message. And the math mode is rendered correctly.

Comment: try adding $ or $$ around your math symbols, e.g., `$100+250*1$` or use latex like this `knitr::latex(100+250*1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using "Xtables" makes it more robust the alignment fallacies:

```
library(xtable)
df <- data.frame(A=c("Hello!", 100, "$x^2+100$"), L=c(10, "World!", "100+250*1"))
table <- xtable(df, caption = "An example", label = "tab:example", col.names = c("Left", "Right"))
footnote <- list(pos = list(-1), command = c('\\multicolumn{2}{r}{Source: Book.}'))
table <- add.to.row(table, footnote)
print(table, include.rownames = FALSE, floating = FALSE, hline.after = c(-1))
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
library(xtable)

# your dataframe
df <- data.frame(A=c("Hello!", 100, "$x^2+100$"), L=c(10, "World!", "100+250*1"))

# Create the object
table <- xtable(df, caption = "An example", label = "tab:example", col.names = c("Left", "Right"))

# Print what you need
print(table, include.rownames = FALSE, floating = FALSE, hline.after = c(-1), footnote = 'Source: Book.')
```

Comment: `Error in add.to.row(table, footnote) : 
  could not find function "add.to.row"`